# How do I know when to retire a climbing harness?

Tags: safety, sport-climbing

I've only been climbing a few months.  I bought [a harness](http://blackdiamondequipment.com/en_US/climbing-harnesses/momentum-harness-BD651068_cfg.html) and have been using it.  I know they don't last forever.

How do I know when to stop using it and buy a new one?

([How should I check climbing equipment to tell whether it is still safe to use?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/592/6596) doesn't talk about harnesses)

Comment: Look up the fallout from Todd Skinners accident, where his belay loop failed.

Comment: Manufacturers' websites could be useful here: for instance, [this Black Diamond page](https://eu.blackdiamondequipment.com/en_IT/qc-lab-strength-of-worn-belay-loops.html) has a harness inspection checklist, and discussion of the accident @mattnz mentioned.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- When it's beyond the lifetime recommended by the manufacturer.
- When you see abrasion or damage that is more than superficial on any of the load-bearing components. This means you have to inspect your harness regularly.
- When it has been in contact with a number of [strongly corrosive substances](https://www.calpaclab.com/nylon-chemical-compatibility-chart/).
- When there is discoloration (indicates excessive exposure to sunlight, which can weaken Nylon).

Here's an article that goes into some more detail: https://www.backcountry.com/explore/when-to-replace-your-rock-climbing-harness

Comment: Well I've only used it a few times and it's already showing "abrasion".  How much is too much?

Comment: @endolith Maybe you could add to your post a picture of the "abrasion" in your harness? Most of the times "a few months" (or "a few times") of normal use shouldn't show significant abrasion.

Comment: Well it's not significant now, but I want to know how to identify when it is in the future.

Comment: Just a nit-pick: Nylon does not corrode, there are [some specific chemicals](https://www.calpaclab.com/nylon-chemical-compatibility-chart/) which can dissolve it. Maybe acidic would be more suitable adjective to use.

Comment: @imsodin: if you look at the chart, there are many substances listed with "D-Severe Effect" that are not acids. I'll just add a link to it.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt I know, that's why I wasn't overly happy with that either, but corrosive feels like further from the truth, as it isn't corrosion. Maybe "dissolving", but that sounds bad (as you may have noted, I am neither an expert in the field nor a native English speaker). And anyway, it's definitely nothing important. More practically relevant would be explicitly stating the most common example: Car battery fluid.