# How long can a new climbing rope be safe?

Tags: climbing, top-roping

I have a climbing rope (Maxim, 11mm) that I bought back around 2008-2009 (so it's about 10 years old now).  It has never been used, it's been stored properly, and the sheath and core appear to be in good condition.  It's like new ... just 10 years old.

Is this old rope safe to use for top-rope climbing?

Comment: Hi James. As of now, there are three close votes as a duplicate to the one in Charlie's link. (I haven't voted yet.) It's a little bit different, but is it close enough that you feel comfortable closing this, or would you rather let us know why this is different or the answer on the other isn't helpful. That one also has a related link to [this one](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/592/) about checking equipment for safety which might be helpful. Will you look around and see if the answers suffice?

Comment: Also, you won't get notified if this closes, so make sure you keep an eye on it!

Comment: In general every manufacturer has a maximum usage period depending on the intensity of the use. Typically a rope that is never used will hit this limit after 8-10 years. After that the manufacturer does not guarantee any safety and you use it at your own risk. This is the only safe answer anyone can give you.

Comment: The question that this one supposedly duplicates refers to a situation where the OP is obtaining a rope from someone else. The conclusion of the answer seems to hinge on this. So, in my view, they are different questions.

Comment: I agree that the question is slightly different, but the answer linked contains the information I'm looking for in the first paragraph. Namely, that ropes can be stored for quite some time with minimal (if any) degradation so long as they haven't been exposed to sunlight, harsh chemicals, or strained over a sharp edge.  This rope has had none of those stressors, so it should be OK.  The biggest risk factor mentioned in the linked post has to do with usage by prior owners.  As I have owned this rope myself all this time, it is not an issue.

So I'm happy to leave it closed as duplicate! :)