# When did the manufacture date became mandatory written on labels in Europe?

Tags: safety, rock-climbing, ropes, safety-standards, harness

Equipment like ropes, slings, harness, etc. have the manufacture date on their label. I still have some older equipment without any manufacture date written on their label.

When did it become compulsory to be written at the label?

... just for calming, I plan to reanimate my hobby, I am going to replace my stuff anyway.

Comment: Harnesses that comply with ANSI Z359.11-2014 need the date of manufacture as part of the labeling.

Comment: @JonCuster Just a reminder that not everyone lives in the US. OP lives in Switzerland according to their bio, and I imagine the first instance of it being a legal requirement to have a printed manufacturing date is going to vary by jurisdiction. I think all the ISO/EN/BS/ANSI standards are based on the original UIAA standard, so looking there would be my first port of call. Also, I believe that most reputable equipment manufactuers were following UIAA guidance long before it became legally compulsory.

Comment: The first UIAA safety standard was published in 1960 and internationally ratified in 1965. Can't currently find a copy of it to see if it included manufacturer date from the off though.

Comment: @Darren Well, certainly my equipment is not that old. It's maybe 20 years old.

Comment: @Darren - hence why it was a comment. Note that UIAA standards are set up to use the CE mark, which is not worldwide either. Standards tend to evolve towards mutual conformance over time, mostly, so if one thinks date labeling is a good idea then others move that way as well - keeps the labeling easier for meeting multiple standards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found these ones at Edelrid webpage [EN 12277:2007](https://avs.edelrid.com/images/attribut/EN_12277.pdf).

> The following compulsory information is provided by the manufacturer on the product:
>
> - Type of harness / model designation;
> - Information explaining how to correctly fasten and secure any buckles or adjustment devices;
> - Label or pictogram to indicate that type D harnesses may not be used alone;
> - Label or pictogram to indicate the correct ‚tie-in-method‘;
> - **Year of manufacture**, manufacturer;
> - Reference to user manual;
> - Size, if applicable; maximum weight and size ranges, only for type B harnesses;
> - CE mark with 4-digit identification number;

For ropes it would be [EN 892:2012-11](https://avs.edelrid.com/images/attribut/EN_892.pdf)

> The following compulsory information is supplied by the manufacturer
> on the product:
>
> - Manufacturer/trading name;
> - **Year manufactured**;
> - Length specification;
> - Type of rope/diameter;
> - Symbol for
>
>   - Single rope
>   - Half rope
>   - Twin rope
> - CE mark with 4-digit identification number

And for slings/quickdraws it would be [EN 566:2006](https://avs.edelrid.com/images/attribut/EN_566.pdf)

> The following compulsory information is supplied by the manufacturer
> on the product:
>
> - Name of manufacturer;
> - Breaking strength;
> - EN 566;
> - **Year manufactured**;
> - CE mark with 4-digit identification number

To summarize, if your textile equipment does not have the manufacture date printed on the label, then it is older than 10 years (or even 15 years) - and should be replaced.

Just for sake of completeness:

- Helmets: [EN 12492](https://avs.edelrid.com/images/attribut/EN_12492.pdf)
- Carabiners: [EN 12275](https://avs.edelrid.com/images/attribut/EN_12275.pdf)
- Accessory cords: [EN 564](https://avs.edelrid.com/images/attribut/EN_564.pdf)
- Tapes: [EN 565](https://avs.edelrid.com/images/attribut/EN_565.pdf)
- Ascenders: [EN 567](https://avs.edelrid.com/images/attribut/EN_567.pdf)
- Ice anchors/screws/piton: [EN 568](https://avs.edelrid.com/images/attribut/EN_568.pdf)
- Crampons: [EN 893](https://avs.edelrid.com/images/attribut/EN_893.pdf)
- Energy absorber: [EN 958](https://avs.edelrid.com/images/attribut/EN_958.pdf)
- Lanyards: [EN 354](https://avs.edelrid.com/images/attribut/EN_354.pdf)
- Nuts: [EN 12270](https://avs.edelrid.com/images/attribut/EN_12270.pdf)
- Camming devices: [EN 12276](https://avs.edelrid.com/images/attribut/EN_12276.pdf)
- Pulley: [EN 12278](https://avs.edelrid.com/images/attribut/EN_12278.pdf)
- Ice tool: [EN 13089](https://avs.edelrid.com/images/attribut/EN_13089.pdf)
- Connectors: [EN 362](https://avs.edelrid.com/images/attribut/EN_362.pdf)

Comment: Note that the dates of the European Norms you quote are the dates of their publication.  ENs usually have a grace period of a year or two before they must be complied with, giving manufacturers time to adjust.  But your dates do give a good guide.